# ¿Es posible poner un if en un array?

Tags: php

dispongo de un foro, pero me gustaría hacer algo, y no sé si es posible.

No sé si es posible poner un if is_locked dentro de un array:

```
'lock' => 
  array(
    'test' => 'can_lock', 
    'text' => empty($context['is_locked']) ? 'set_lock' : 'set_unlock', 
    'image' => 'admin_lock.gif', 
    'lang' => true,
    'custom' => 'onclick="return confirm(\'' . $txt['are_sure_lock_topic'] . '\');"', 
    'url' => $scripturl . '?action=lock;topic=' . $context['current_topic'] . '.' . $context['start'] . ';' . $context['session_var'] . '=' . $context['session_id']
  );
```

Intento poner un if después de 'custom' pero no, no va. Lo que quiero es que verifique si esta el is_locked y enviar una alerta en especifico, mientras que si verifica que está el is_unlocked se envie otra alerta.

Gracias. Aclaro que apenas sé de php, pero aprenderé.

Comment: Pon el código como lo estás intentando y el error. No veo ningún `if`

Comment: Hola, Cedano. Como mencioné, apenas sé de php. No me acuerdo muy bien, pero salía algo de unexpected if '.

Comment: Entiendo, pero pon un ejemplo simple de lo que quieres evaluar en ese `if` y dinos por qué no usas un ternario por ejemplo en lugar del `if`

Comment: Algo asi: `'custom' => if ($context['is_locked']) 'onclick="return confirm(\'' . $txt['are_sure_lock_topic'] . '\');"'`

Comment: Puedes usar un ternario, por ejemplo: `$arr=array('msg'=> ($isLocked) ?  'bloqueado' : 'Desbloqueado');` Aquí `$isLocked` tendría un valor `true` o `false` y `msg` adquiriría `bloqueado` o `desbloqueado` según el caso. Otra opción es definir una variable y luego meterla en el array. Meter un `if` tal cual es imposible porque su estructura rompe la estructura del array por los símbolos que debería usar: `(){};` y aunque los admitiera, ¿cómo se va a asignar el valor ¿? ... mucho tomate para un pobre array.

Comment: Muchas gracias.